# Data Backup from aws to other cloud storage for backups if aws account get hacked

Tags: security, amazon-web-services

We are thinking to make a backup of all our AWS data (RDS and S3) to some other cloud sources, because there is a possibility that a developer of company AWS account get hacked. The hacker could then can delete everything from AWS. So I have two question here:

1. Is my assumption correct regarding deletion of entire data by someone?
2. What is the best way to curb this? Basically, I can only think of using some other service as data backup apart from AWS, if anyone has done something like this, it would be very nice to know how they achieved it.

Comment: just wondering, I was not able to find the same question. that's why posted this. But then what is the point of devoting this? Strange things in the simple world sometime.

Answer (score 5):

The insider-threat problem has existed for as long as we've had IT systems, Amazon is no different. What is different is that Amazon has a single God-level account that can delete the entire infrastructure in a few clicks. The advice for AWS is the same for other things, but boils down to:

- Ensure separation of privilege. DBA-types should have different access from sysadmin-types, who should have different access from dev-types.
- Don't give everyone access everything. That's the easy way out and is where evil lurks.
- Make sure the God account is only usable by as few people as possible, and use 2-factor if at all doable.

  - Corollary: IAM accounts with Full Access to everything are almost as bad as access to the God account. Make sure IAM-FullAccess accounts are in as few hands as possible.
- It's a good idea to appoint 'backup admins' who have access to S3 buckets no one else does. This backstops you from delete-everything insider-attacks.

Backing up outside of AWS entirely is quite doable, but the engineering to make it work is pretty major (especially for hosted services such as RDS). AWS itself advises structuring your security to prevent that from happening, and if it does the impact is localized.